# How to pass this variable of checkbox from java method to Java-Script method

Tags: javascript, java, html, checkbox

I need to pass checkbox Boolean value(True or False) from below java method to java script function.

```
    java method ::   

     M1() 
        {
          generatedXML.append("<div id=checkboxes> ");
          generatedXML.append("<input type=checkbox ");
          generatedXML.append(" onchange=\"setValue('");
          generatedXML.append(obj);
          generatedXML.append("','");
          generatedXML.append('this');
          generatedXML.append("');\"");
        }

JavaScript function::

    function setValue(obj,refr) 
    {
      alert(refr.checked); // i think it will alert true or false??
      //Need Boolean value of checkbox 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the value attribute:

Java:

```
generatedXML.append("<div id='checkboxes'>");
for (String value : values) {
   generatedXML.append(String.format("<input type='checkbox' value='%s' />", value));
}
generatedXML.append("</div>");
```

Javascript: (assuming you are using [jquery](https://jquery.com/))

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#checkboxes > checkbox').change(function() {
      alert($(this).val() + " = " + $(this).checked);
   });
});
```